# How to find the point where graph starts to curve up?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, cluster-analysis

I was trying to find the elbow point for a clustering algorithm. I am able to detect the curve visually but I want to try to locate it in python directly. I tried using kneed library however it gives me point way above the curve, am I using it wrong or is there other way to do it?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2,metric='euclidean',n_jobs=-1)
nbrs = neigh.fit(coords[:,0:2])
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(coords[:,0:2])

distances = np.sort(distances, axis=0)
distances = distances[:,1]
plt.plot(distances)
```

[The graph curves around ~9800](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLv0Q.png)
here coords is a np array with 2 features (coordinates).

using kneed but I get a higher value

```
from kneed import KneeLocator
kn = KneeLocator(indices[:,0],distances,curve='convex',direction='increasing')
distances[kn.elbow]

#I get 10146
```

EDIT:
Sorry if the problem was not clear, simply it is

given x and y where
x is a simple array consisting of numbers from 1 to n (number of data points in y)
and y is a array with points (n points) that grows exponentially up,

now what I want is that given this I want to find the x point or the y point where the graph starts to curve up.

eg. this is the distances array

```
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.03363485, 0.03682148,
       0.07781013])
```

[This is the graph image and red point is what I want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kImva.png)

Comment: 1- please provide the underlying data, 2- please provide the explicit point that **you** consider visually (there is no unique definition of "elbow", a different person might choose another point)

Comment: Try adjusting the [sensitivity value](https://kneed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html#s)?

Comment: @СергейКох please check the question again, please do ask if its still not clear

Comment: @mozway please check the question again, please do comment if still not clear. What I am looking for is given data points when plotted on graph (find the point where it starts to grow. You can assume that graph will always be growing upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mozway notes in the comments, the elbow/knee is not a uniquely defined point, so can be arbitrary. I think the `kneed` algorithm essentially tries to find the point on your curve with the largest second derivative, but because your curve is so steeply rising at the end it finds that the largest second derivative is at the last points.

A somewhat arbitrary method you could use, is to first fit a straight line between your first and last point, then get the residual and then find the point where the residual's gradient is minimised. This might go along the lines of (with some faked data to look a bit like yours):

```py
import numpy as np

# generate data
a = 10000000.0
b = 0.05
c = 0.003
scale = 1e-14

x = np.arange(0, 10500)
y = scale * (a * x + b * np.exp(c * x))

# get a line joining the first and last points
m = (y[-1] - y[0]) / (x[-1] - x[0])
c = y[0]

# make the line
line = m * x + c

# get the residuals
res = y - line

# get gradient of the residuals
grad = np.diff(res)

# get index of minimum gradient
midx = np.argmin(np.abs(grad))

# plot everything
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, height_ratios=[2, 1])

ax[0].plot(x, y, label="Data")
ax[0].plot(x, line, ls="--", label="Line")
ax[0].plot(x[midx], y[midx], "o", label="Elbow")
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].plot(x, res)
ax[1].set_ylabel("Residual")
```

[image]

In this case (due to its arbitrary nature), if the data continued to larger values of x, the knee position would move further to the right, i.e., it is not a fixed defined point in this method.

Comment: thankyou this is giving better results than kneed I will try to test it on my other data more then check back to this post and update it :D